# inArray is not working fine with ajax responce

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, split

Hi i am trying to write implement `inArray` and having this issue how can resolve this..?

this is my script:

```
success: function (response) {
$.each(response['courceResults'], function(k, cource) {

if(cource.membership_chosen == 3){
 var mystr =cource.category_chosen;
 var results = mystr.split(",");
```

from the above code i have alerted and the results are following:

```
mystr = 1,13,3,4
cource.id = 7,7,3,5,5,5,6,7,8,9,9
```

i want the results which are there in the mystr variable how can i do that..?

this what i have tried:

```
if ( $.inArray( cource.id , results )) { 'PAID';     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According `$.inArray` documentation

> Search for a specified value within an array and return its index (or
>   -1 if not found).

You have to check for the return value. It is not a boolean

```
if($.inArray(cource.id, results) != -1) {
    ... // Rest of the code
}
```

Comment: Is my split is correct. ? And is it returning as array..?

Comment: `mystr` & `results` looks ok to me, but my doubt is in `cource.id`. Hope its a single value

Comment: can you help me in the if condition i want to write "paid"  can you answer here not getting conatination..! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42548016/show-variable-is-not-working-in-ajax-response